# How to change the color of each row of tablix in rdlc?

Tags: rdlc, ssrs-tablix

I am new to rdlc, in rdlc I have a tab lix that can have max of 10 row, I want to assign each row a unique color. I found a solution for even and odd row color, but I want to assign each row a unique color, how is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Best way I can think of is to make the colour of the row based on a function. Then define an array of 10 colour values and use the RowNumber function to pick which element in the array to use as that rows colour. The choose function would do most of this logic for you:

```
=Choose(RowNumber(Nothing),"#ffff33","#aaaa66", "#333399")
```

Comment: You can do this without a function as well.  Set a report variable as an array of color values such as `=Split("#0000FF,#00FF00,#00FFFF,#FF0000,#FF00FF,#FFFF00,#FFFFFF",",")`, and then use RowNumber as an indexer in the fill expression: `=Variables!ColorArray.Value(RowNumber(Nothing))`

Comment: The choose function is a part of VBA and isn't really any different than the split function.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/824bz7dy(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: =Choose(RowNumber(Nothing),"#ffff33","#aaaa66", "#333399","#ffff33","#aaaa66", "#333399")
This expression works for first two row, but next all row color is white

Comment: my guess the problem is with the RowNumber(Nothing) depeding on how you've grouped/ layed out your data in the tablix there might need to be something in the RowNumber(...) function instead of "Nothing". What might be worth doing is adding another column and just putting the RowNumber function into that column to see what numbers it is returning.